# Changing the integration variables for Residual Gibbs free energy (EOS)

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics

I am stuck trying to derive the residual Gibbs free energy; though, I succeeded deriving the departure function but stuck with the residual part.

The departure function is 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}G(\text{departure})}{RT}=\int(Z-1)\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{P}
$$
where 
$$G(\text{departure}))=G-G(\text{Ideal Gas})=\frac{ZRT}{P}\mathrm{d}P- \frac{RT}{P}\mathrm{d}P
$$

To get the residual Gibbs free energy we need to write the integral 
$$
\int(Z-1)\frac{dP}{P}
$$ 
in terms of molar volume and $T$ instead of $P$ and $T$.

The final answer is 
$$
\frac{dG(\text{residual})}{RT}=\int(Z-1)({VdV)}+Z-1-ln(Z).
$$

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to replace dP/P with dP=RTd(Z/V) and P=ZRT/V It would be a lot easier if we replace V with ru(molar density)